# Storing Database Table as a backup in Xamarin Forms to use from device to device

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I have been doing a lot of reading on Xamarin Essentials and saving data in the app data directory.
What I am trying to accomplish is have this one table automatically backup when something gets added or removed so the user can always see that list even if they switch devices.

To be clear, the device has a whole local database, but the majority of that data is being stored in a db file that gets saved in the main directory and then copied upon app start up. The only data that is not preloaded is the user's favorite's.
The app itself does not contain a login, and I am not managing user info. When the user likes an item it loads up as an item on their favorites list aka gets added to Favorites Table. I would like only the Favorites Table to be backed up, because the other data can be retrieved.

Mind you this back up is so a user can take their information on whatever device they move to, if they install it as backup. I am assuming the automatic updates are somehow connected to the users account (e.g Apple ID or Google Account)?

I came across an interesting article that goes into depth on what items are OK to put in what directories since you run the risk of getting your app rejected by the App Store.
https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin-forms-and-the-open-question-of-where-to-store-your-files

I just haven't been able to figure out how to save only one table from a database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just export that one table as json and save as a file

Comment: huh interesting so how would I retrieve it and have it be a db table again?

Comment: Hi, first you need to convert the table to model data , then use Json to **Serialize** model Object to `string`. Then you can pass the string to server or other where. When you need the back up, you could get the json string and use json **Deserialize** Object to model data. Last you can put the model data to table in database. About json using could refer to [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Comment: do you actually need to query the data, or do joins to other tables?  If not, then do you actually need the data, or can you just serialize/deserialize it from a json file to an in-memory object?

Comment: Hi @Jason so yes I do 2 joins from this table, but theoretically this is a backup only. The data is still being saved in the local table "Favorites", which is where I do my querying. I just want to always have that data synced in case the person decides to download the app to their iPad as well. You know so the data is not gone. i guess I would only deserialize the data upon first time start up or upon first time start up after a new version.

Comment: so you just need to import/export that data as it changes

Comment: @Jason, yes basically. I won't be calling it back from the app data path unless its a fresh download or on new version of app.

Comment: this directory, does sync automatically correct? Like I mentioned I've been doing reading but everywhere it says automatic backups which I am assuming means the app syncs with the user's account?